# How to show all previous messages when user is added in signalr group?

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I have a chat application developed using asp.net c# and signalr. It starts as one to one chat application but once a group is created users are allowed to add other online users in that group. I need that whenever a new user is added in chat group all previous messages of that group are also displayed to him as well. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

Use the `OnConnected` event of the hub to detect that a new user has connected. You need to keep track of all messages that have been sent (for that particuar group) and play them back to the client by calling a method on his side and passing the list of messages.